# java print XContentBuilder Json string

Tags: java

I use an XContentBuilder object to build a Json string.

```
XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
                .field(Constants.OSM_ID, doc.getOsmId())
                .field(Constants.OSM_TYPE, doc.getOsmType())
                .field(Constants.OSM_KEY, doc.getTagKey())
                .field(Constants.OSM_VALUE, doc.getTagValue())
                .field(Constants.IMPORTANCE, doc.getImportance());
```

Now I would like to System.out the resulting Json String. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finish building:

```
String s = builder.string();
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Thanks. Straight forward enough to be missed :)

Comment: stupidity, why would the team not implement toString like a human being

Comment: This methods seems removed in the latest .

Answer (score 47):

since elastic client v6.3

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.Strings;

String json = Strings.toString(builder);
```

[see elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html#java-docs-index-generate-helpers)